# Words with finite critical exponent

Tags: gn.general-topology, combinatorics-on-words

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite set. Is there a nice characterization of the subset of $S\subset \mathcal{A}^\omega$ such that every $w\in S$ has finite [critical exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent_of_a_word)? Of course $S$ has measure zero (with respect to the uniform product measure), but what can be said about its topological properties?

Comment: The set is also $F_\sigma$ and meager - for every $n$, the set of words which contain an $n$-th power is open and dense.

Comment: That is correct. Indeed, the map $\kappa_n$ defined here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/376516/167834 is continuous on its zero set, which is thus $G_\delta$. Since it is also dense ($\kappa_n$ for instance vanishes on $\mathbb{Q}$), by Baire category theorem it is residual, so that its complement is $F_\sigma$ and meagre.

Comment: What else can be said from a topological point of view?